# C idiom for multi-layer buffered input with processing

Tags: c, io, bitwise

I'm writing a bit-level IO code that handles endianness conversion for the `short/uint16_t` type in the IO subroutines. Here's the code:

```c
#ifndef header
#define header 1

#include <assert.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct {
    FILE *fp;
    uint8_t word[2];
    short le, wp; // little-endian flag, and position (0 and 1) in word.
    short filled;
    uint32_t buf;
} iohandle_t;

#endif /* header */

static int Input1Byte(iohandle_t *fp)
{
    int ret;

    if( !fp->wp )
    {
        fp->wp = fread(fp->word, 1, 2, fp->fp);
        if( fp->wp != 2 ) return -1; // error propagation
    }

    ret = fp->word[(2 - fp->wp) ^ fp->le];
    fp->wp --;
    return ret;
}

static inline int min(int a, int b){ return a < b ? a : b; }

int BitsInput(iohandle_t *fp, int bits)
{
    int ret = 0;
    int plen = min(bits, 8);

    while( plen )
    {
        while( fp->filled < plen )
        {
            int c = Input1Byte(fp);
            if( c < 0 ) return -1; // error propagation.
            
            fp->buf |= (uint32_t)c << (32 - fp->filled - 8);
            fp->filled += 8;
        }
        
        ret <<= plen;
        ret |= fp->buf >> (32 - plen);

        fp->buf <<= plen;
        fp->filled -= plen;
        bits -= plen;
        plen = min(bits, 8);
    }

    return ret;
}
```

I'm handling the conversion at this level to abstract it away from higher-level bit-stream semantics processing. Obviously, this code is bare minimum and not very robust to exceptional situations.

When I look back to this code after writing it several days ago, I realized, if it were to be more robust, for each level of buffering, there needs 2 counters - 1 "filled" counter, and 1 "evicted" counter. As well as the fact that, I probably need additional advice, and sharing the results can be useful to others.

So **Q**: What are the idioms for writing multi-layer buffered input with processing like the example above? Most importantly, is there a recurring *code template* that people can reuse?

Comment: Thank you for writing `(32 - ... - 8)` rather than `(24 - ... )`, I really do appreciate it. But wouldn't it be simpler to bump by eight _before_ that line? // `fp->fp` is the _wrong_ identifier -- consider `h->fp` when renaming that handle. // You have several loop invariants. Write some comments in the struct definition and in the loop so the Gentle Reader will understand Author's Intent rather than having to make buggy guesses about it.

Comment: @J_H The very true low-hanging fruits that I should've picked, thanks! However, using `h->fp` is likely going to conflict with other `h` that I may use (a project of mine that involve hash functions and context already suffer from confusion with `hx`, `hashctx`, and `hashfuncs`). The main purpose of asking on the other hand, is that I want to make some kind of canonical post when people seek idiom(s) when writing layered IO processing.

Comment: If the stream has only one byte, we hit an error immediately. Doesn't look right to me.

Comment: @vnp, Rest assured, the length of each synchronization frame of the said bitstream is always a multiply of 16 bits (otherwise I won't be handling word-level endianness). But that may be relevant to other bitstream formats.